# Django static files 404 on server, although working locally

Tags: python, django, apache, static

I have deployed a django application on an apache server using WSGI but the static files give me 404 errors although everything worked fine on my PC using Django's development server.

My apache2.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /srv/App/App/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /srv/App

<Directory /srv/App/App>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/app/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

sample of how I call static files through my templates

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/main.css" %}'>
```

The only thing different than my local version of the app is that my STATIC_URL on settings.py doesn't include the '/app' part. According to Chrome's Developer Tools the URL of my static files is:

```
http://.../app/static/css/main.css
```

(using the static file of my template example)
which I think should be right and can not understand the reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any `Alias` directives in Apache configuration telling Apache where your static files are and what URL you want them to appear under. See:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to run this?

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that comes too often. You have to:

- Specify `STATIC_ROOT`
- Run `collectstatic`
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` is not needed for live (handled by Apache).

Take a look at [Django documentation: Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#deployment)

Comment: I have added STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/app/static' (STATIC_URL left as is) and run collectstatic but the problem insists although the files are copied to the directory of STATIC_ROOT var. If I remove the STATICFILES_DIRS it leaves the static files of my '...App/static' folder out.